# How can I prove the correctness of the Hoshen–Kopelman algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof

I'd like to formally prove the correctness of Hoshen–Kopelman algorithm (link here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshen%E2%80%93Kopelman_algorithm). Anyway I don't know what is the right approach. At first I wanted to prove it by induction (as it obviously works for a 1x1 grid), but I got stuck.

Comment: The first step is to precisely state what it means for it to be correct.

Comment: I think that in this case the algorithm is correct if all the clusters are labeled correctly

Comment: I suggest you try to formalize that in a precise way.  For instance, such a formalization will need to identify what the mathematical definition of a "cluster" is, and what "labeled correctly" is.

Comment: You were right. I mean at first I was thinking "it's obvious what a cluster is", but then I realised it wasn't obvious at all. I think I found a good formal definition of cluster (in this context of course) and after that the proof of the algorithm wasn't too difficult. So thank you. If you're interested I can post my "solution" (even though I'm not sure yet it is correct)